# How to validate time values in two dropdown fields against each other using JS/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, range, dropdown

I have a form with "From" and "To" dropdowns that contain time values.
It looks like this:

```
From
<select class="from">
<option value="09:00 AM">09:00 AM</option>
<option value="10:00 AM">10:00 AM</option>
<option value="10:15 AM">10:15 AM</option>
<option value="10:30 AM">10:30 AM</option>
<option value="10:45 AM">10:45 AM</option>
<option value="11:00 AM">11:00 AM</option>
...
</select>

To
<select class="to">
<option value="10:00 AM">10:00 AM</option>
<option value="10:15 AM">10:15 AM</option>
<option value="10:30 AM">10:30 AM</option>
<option value="10:45 AM">10:45 AM</option>
<option value="11:00 AM">11:00 AM</option>
<option value="11:15 AM">11:15 AM</option>
<option value="11:30 AM">11:30 AM</option>
<option value="11:45 AM">11:45 AM</option>
<option value="12:00 PM">12:00 PM</option>
...
</select>
```

I want to prevent people from being able to select '**from**' that is equal or later than '**to**', e.g. **from 11am to 9am** and other combinations that don't make sense.

I'm using [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) and jQuery.
I included date.min.js script and got the following code that almost does the trick:

```
$('.from').on('change', function(e) {
  var from_time = Date.parse($(this).val());

  // Ensure 1 hour difference
  var from_time_adj = new Date();
  from_time_adj.setTime(from_time.getTime() + (60 * 60 * 1000));

  $('.to option').each(function(index, el) {
    var to_time = Date.parse($(el).val());
    if (to_time < from_time_adj) {
      $(el).attr('disabled', true);
    }
  });
});


$('.to').on('change', function(e) {
  var to_time = Date.parse($(this).val());

  // Ensure 1 hour difference
  var to_time_adj = new Date();
  to_time_adj.setTime(to_time.getTime() - (60 * 60 * 1000));

  $('.from option').each(function(index, el) {
    var from_time = Date.parse($(el).val());
    if (from_time > to_time_adj) {
      $(el).attr('disabled', true);
    }
  });
});
```

Here's the whole 'almost working' thing: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zpmLyx90/)

It becomes weird at some point, for example:

Step 1: Set **from 11:00am** - it's OK

Step 2: Set **to 2:00pm** - it's OK

Step 3: Set **to 8:00pm** - Oops! At this point **from** has disabled everything after 1:00pm

What gives? It starts doing this weird thing after 2 or so changes. Further attempts to play with from/to values show this.

I realize I have a bug in the code logic, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable too:

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/h28g2L75/)

```js
$('.from').on('change', function(e) {
  var from_time = Date.parse($(this).val());

  var from_time_adj = new Date();
  from_time_adj.setTime(from_time.getTime() + (60 * 60 * 1000));

  $('.to option').each(function(index, el) {
    var to_time = Date.parse($(el).val());
    $(el).attr('disabled', to_time < from_time_adj); // disables when statement is true, enables when false
  });
});

$('.to').on('change', function(e) {

  var to_time = Date.parse($(this).val());
  var to_time_adj = new Date();

  to_time_adj.setTime(to_time.getTime() - (60 * 60 * 1000));
  $('.from option').each(function(index, el) {
    var from_time = Date.parse($(el).val());
    $(el).attr('disabled', to_time > to_time_adj); // disables when statement is true, enables when false
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan. I'm not too advanced in this, so I didn't fully get it :( How do I re-enable those options I've previously disabled in correct order?

Comment: Using the test you have instead of true

Comment: You mean changing `$(el).attr('disabled', true);` to `$(el).attr('disabled', to_time < from_time_adj);`? I'm afraid I don't get it...

Comment: `true` is a boolean, the result of `to_time > from_time_adj` is also a boolean, e.g. either true or false. It will do the job: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/h28g2L75/

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. Try setting from 11am to 2pm and check from dropdown again. Your code only validates one-way - when you first set from X to Y. On 2nd try you can choose from 8pm to 2pm etc.

Comment: Can you give examples?

Comment: Ok, I'm looking at your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/h28g2L75/. Step 1 - set From 2pm; set To 7pm. Now From has options 7pm and later active, so I can select from 8pm to 7pm. Step 2 - repeat Step 1, set all values to sane (From < To) and it'll happen again: once you set To to a later time, e.g. 5pm - From will have options 6pm and so on.

Comment: Bug. I had repeated the from_time

Comment: But the issue is still there. I am too tired to look. I will look later

Comment: Yeah, I should have mentioned I fixed the bug with repeated from_time in my copy, sorry. Thanks for checking this, much appreciated.

Comment: I thought I had a good idea (and I had until I noticed I DO need to take time into account, so now it is complicated again: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/h28g2L75/

Comment: Anyone else can step in here and shed some light? :)